# ASP.NET 5 Conceptual Questions

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, kestrel-http-server

1. If I remove Kestrel dependency from project.json my web application wont start. Does that mean ASP.NET 5 is dependent on Kestrel? Is it a replacement of IIS?
2. Is DNX a collective name for .NET Core and Full .NET with CLI features?
3. In Windows, there is IIS to host ASP.NET 5 apps. What is the equivalent for Linux? nginx or Apache maybe?

Comment: seriously, how did someone vote to close this under "unclear what you're asking "? Questions are very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. If I remove Kestrel dependency from project.json my web application wont start. Does that mean ASP.NET 5 is dependent on Kestrel? Is it a replacement of IIS?

No. However, it requires a server. There are a few layers for HTTP applications (simplified version):

- Bootstrapping: DNX
- Hosting: which knows how to wire the server and your application together.
- Server: which knows how to handle HTTP requests.
- Application Layer: your application layer.

So, you can replace the server with any compatible one, doesn't have to be Kestrel.

> 2. Is DNX a collective name for .NET Core and Full .NET with CLI features?

No, it's just the bootstrapper which loads the proper CLR version and gets you up and going. It will be probably replaced by [dotnet CLI](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/having-a-look-at-dotnet-cli-tool-and--net-native-compilation-in-linux). That story is a bit vague today but keep your eyes open for new announcements.

> 3. In Windows, there is IIS to host ASP.NET 5 apps. What is the equivalent for Linux? nginx or Apache maybe?

Anything that suits you. That could be even HAProxy. The team will probably have boilerplate stuff with one of them but at the end of the day, it's all up to you. Watch below two videos, they have good info on server story and Linux:

- [ASP.NET 5: Kestrel](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/ASPNET-Events/ASPNET-Fall-Sessions/ASPNET-5-Kestrel)
- [ASP.NET 5: Considerations for Production Linux Environments](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/ASPNET-Events/ASPNET-Fall-Sessions/ASPNET-5-Considerations-for-Production-Linux-Environments)